# Generate number from 1-5 based on user ID?

Tags: php

Building a web application and would like to assign each user one of 5 default avatars (as a Gravatar fallback) based on their user ID.

User 1 would be assigned avatar 1
User 2 would be assigned avatar 2
User 3 would be assigned avatar 3
User 4 would be assigned avatar 4
User 5 would be assigned avatar 5
User 6 would be assigned avatar 1

And so on...

How can I convert the user's ID to an "avatar ID" using PHP? I understand there's some basic math involved, but it's late my brain isn't functioning right now.

Thanks!

Comment: You could check if the ID is divisible by 5 if it is assign avatar5, if not check if it's divisibly by 4 if it is assign avatar4, etc etc. However this seems a lot more wasteful than keeping track of the last avatar assigned to a user

Answer (score 4):

Simply do [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 5:

```
$avatar = ($id % 5) + 1; // 1 through 5
```

I.e., you obtain the remainder from dividing the user ID (`$id`) with 5 (0-4), then add 1.

---

**EDIT**: `$avatar = (($id - 1) % 5) + 1;` if you want 1 => 1 ... 6 => 1 instead of shifted one place, cf. [demo](http://ideone.com/z4bt04).

Answer (score 0):

Use `User id mod 5` to generate a number from 0 to 4

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you have to do is taking the modulus 5 of the id Number. (assuming that id number is like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10......

```
$avtarId= ($userId % 5) +1;
```

1 is added since avatar id is like 1,2,3,4,5 not 0,1,2,3,4